# Mathematica truncates output from an external python session

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, data, external-calls

I am running an external python session in Mathematica via `ExternalEvaluate`. It sends commands to the Bloomberg API in command prompt on Microsoft Windows.

I start the session with

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"->"String"]
```

then I run

```
data = 
 ExternalEvaluate[session, 
  "blp.bds(tickers='BG1120297 Corp',flds=['Involved Participants'])"]
```

but Mathematica is truncating the output, providing a truncated table:

[image]

If I run this directly in command prompt, by decreasing the font I can fit all the data onto the screen (otherwise python truncates it in command prompt). Can I get the same thing to work for Mathematica, so it doesn't cut off the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can change options such as `pandas.options.display.max_columns` to prevent that from happening ([Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html)).

I couldn't understand why you used `"Python"->"String"`. If you remove `->"String"` Mathematica automatically convert the data frame for you into an `Association` and you can display it in different format inside Mathematica.

But if you want to keep it without changing options, calling

```
Column @ StringSplit[ExternalEvaluate[session, "blp.bds(...).to_string()"], "\\n"]
```

will print the table in a formatted form or

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, "blp.bds(...).to_numpy().tolist()"]
```

for not-formatted form.

Comment: Thank you! To answer your question, the reasons I tentatively used the `String` type was to get the table output at all. With `Expression` I just get the final row (but it is now a formatted expression, and all columns are available).